# DataTable shows 0 records when I close all of my Group Rows?

Tags: jquery, datatables, grouping, rows

I am trying to use row grouping in my DataTables. I have reached one milestone of grouping the rows but my Collapsing functionality is not working fine. When I am collapsing all the groups by DataTable shows 0 records. I need to show at least the group rows so I can show data again.

[image]

Following is my code:

```
var collapsedRows = [];
var table;
var groupCollapseFilter = function (groupName) {
    return function (settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter) {
         return searchData[3].indexOf(groupName) == -1;
    };
};

$(function () {

    table = $("#MyTable").DataTable({

            "order": [[3, 'asc']],
            "paging": false,
            drawCallback: function () {

                var api = this.api();
                var displayRowIds = api.settings()[0].aiDisplay;
                var rows = api.rows(displayRowIds).nodes();
                var last = null;

                for (var r = 0, rMax = collapsedRows.length; r < rMax; r++) 
                {
                    $(rows).eq(0).before(collapsedRows[r]);
                    $(collapsedRows[r]).addClass("collapsed");
                }

                api.table().rows(displayRowIds)
                    .every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {

                    var data = this.data();

                    if (last !== data[3]) {

                        $(rows).eq(rowLoop).before(

                         '<tr class="group"><td colspan="7">' + data[3] + '</td></tr>'
                        );

                        last = data[3];
                    }

           });
      }

 });
```

Now, Implementing the Click Functionality:

```
 $("#MyTable").on('click', 'tr.group', function () {

        var groupName = $(this.children[0]).text();

        if ($(this).hasClass("collapsed")) {
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.splice($.fn.dataTable.ext.search.indexOf(groupCollapseFilter(groupName)), 1);
            $(this).removeClass("collapsed");
            collapsedRows.splice(collapsedRows.indexOf(this), 1);
            table.draw();
        } else {
            collapsedRows.push(this);
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(groupCollapseFilter(groupName));
            table.draw();
        }
 });
```

I am following [this tutorial.](http://live.datatables.net/nozofiko/3/edit)

Comment: Why wont you use the RowGroup extension? Here is a completely 1:1 version of this "guide" -> https://datatables.net/extensions/rowgroup/examples/initialisation/simple.html

Comment: @davidkonrad I also need collapsing functionality in it. How can I add collapsing functionality? Is there any extension?

Answer (score 0):

> Requirement :
>
> - You want Collapsing functionality
> - Also Collapsing all the groups by DataTable shows Groping Title

Please check below code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        "columnDefs": [
            { "visible": false, "targets": 2 }
        ],
        "order": [[ 2, 'asc' ]],
        "displayLength": 25,
        "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
            var api = this.api();
            var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();

            var last=null;
 
            var groupadmin = []; 
 
            api.column(2, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {

                if ( last !== group ) {
                    $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                        '<tr class="group" id="'+i+'"><td colspan="5">'+group+'</td></tr>'
                    );
                    groupadmin.push(i);
                    last = group;
                }
            } );
            
            for( var k=0; k < groupadmin.length; k++){
                  // Code added for adding class to sibling elements as "group_<id>"  
                  $("#"+groupadmin[k]).nextUntil("#"+groupadmin[k+1]).addClass(' group_'+groupadmin[k]); 
                  // Code added for adding Toggle functionality for each group
                  $("#"+groupadmin[k]).click(function(){
                        var gid = $(this).attr("id");
                         $(".group_"+gid).slideToggle(300);
                  });
            }
        }
    } );
} );
```

```css
body {
  font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}

tr.group,
tr.group:hover {
    background-color: #ddd !important;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sidney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>               
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*

I have enhanced your javascript function.

*/

var collapsedRows = [];
var table;
var groupCollapseFilter = function (groupName) {
    return function (settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter) {
         return searchData[3].indexOf(groupName) == -1;
    };
};

$(function () {

    table = $("#MyTable").DataTable({

            "order": [[3, 'asc']],
            "paging": false,
            drawCallback: function () {

                var api = this.api();
                var displayRowIds = api.settings()[0].aiDisplay;
                var rows = api.rows(displayRowIds).nodes();
                var last = null;

                for (var r = 0, rMax = collapsedRows.length; r < rMax; r++) 
                {
                    $(rows).eq(0).before(collapsedRows[r]);
                    $(collapsedRows[r]).addClass("collapsed");
                }

                api.table().rows(displayRowIds)
                    .every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {

                    var data = this.data();

                    if (last !== data[3]) {

                        $(rows).eq(rowLoop).before(

                         '<tr class="group"><td colspan="7">' + data[3] + '</td></tr>'
                        );

                        last = data[3];
                    }

           });

/*

Following code will check if the table is empty, then append the collapsed rows to it.

*/
                if (table is empty) {
                    $(table)
                        .find("tbody")
                        .html(collapsedRows);
                }


      }

 });
```

Let me explain what I understood from your code.

1. Grouping the rows based on value in a specific column
2. When you click on the row header, it either collapses or expands.
3. When all the column headers are collapsed, your table is empty. Instead you want to show all the collapsed headers.
4. Thus I modified drawCallback function to have a check. **If the table is empty, append the table with collapsedRows array content.**

Comment: Thanks! I have added few comments. I hope that helps.

Comment: I have fixed the row collapse and expand bug as well in this edit. 
http://live.datatables.net/nozofiko/201/edit